# ant script issue in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, ant

I have created one simple GWT application.I have created build.xml. But when I run it, it gives me following Exception:-
      [Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/user/User.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?].

Please guide me,how to solve this.

Comment: @ dhananjay: please post relevant section of  build.xml

Comment: The error says that .xml is not in your classpath.  What is the classpath that is set for javac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classpath for the GWT compiler (or dev mode) is missing the gwt-user.jar.